# Opencv Android Template Matching in Java

Tags: java, image, templates, opencv, matching

I am trying to create a template matching method for my application. What my app does is able to take in images from the camera or sd and what i need to do is to look for symbols at the corners of the object. I got the code for obtaining the image but i am stuck at trying to do the template matching of the image. Can someone give me a basic code for me to accomplish this task, maybe give me some labels as to what certain variables are. I am new to openCV and still a novice in programming and just want to fully understand what is being done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example which covers template matching in Java :

[Template Matching using JavaCV](https://gist.github.com/obedrios/2625290)

Comment: I tried to use it but was unsure how to load in the bitmap image that was loaded from the sd on the emulator. And im not sure how to load the resultant from this code into a bitmap